# Проблемы с сетевым принтером Xerox work station 7525

Tags: принтер

Установлена на одних машинах mandriva powerpack 2011, на других Windows 7 . Выполняет роли файл-сервера в рабочей группе Windows7. Принтер Xerox work station 7525 печатает с задержками иногда до 15 мин, а иногда сразу. Бвыает не хочет печатать вовсе. Пишет: ожидание ответа от принтера. Перезагружаюсь в Windows7 - печатает без проблем. Делаю вывод - с проводами всё в порядке. Установлены samba, cups.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю ситуация схожа с этой [Не печатает brather 7420R](http://admin.hashcode.ru/questions/3659/%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-brather-7420r)